# Robust clustered errors using the survey package

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, survey

I want to test the hypothesis that the coefficient for tobacco use by age is greater in women than men using the couples data (CR) from the Demographic and Health Surveys (DHS), which has a complex survey design. Tobacco use (yes/no) and age data are sampled from couples in a household. Each row therefore includes columns:

```
household_id, age_female, age_male, tobacco_use_female, tobacco_use_male, ...
     12,          25,        32,           0,                1, ...
     13, ...
```

The survey design would be specified:

```
library(survey)
design <- svydesign(ids = ~v021, strata = ~v023, weights = ~I(v005/1e6), nest = T, data=ALCR51)
```

However, to fit the logistic regression I want, I need to convert to long format:

```
household_id, age, sex, tobacco_use, ...
12,            25,  F,     0, ...
12,            32,  M,     1, ...
13, ...
13, ...
```

The regression model would be specified like so, with the interaction coefficient the term of interest:

`m <- svyglm(tobacco_use ~ age * sex, family = binomial, design)`

But by converting to long format, observations are now clustered within households, thus requiring clustered robust errors or something equivalent. I know how to use the `sandwich` and `lmtest` packages with a standard `glm` model, but not with `svyglm`. I'm a beginner using complex survey designs in general, and the survey package in particular. Any guidance appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`svyglm` always returns standard errors account for the clustering in the design - see the *Notes* section of `?svyglm`.

Comment: Thanks. My worry is that by converting the data to long format, I've introduced household level clustering that is not accounted for in the design specification.

Comment: @EdHagen you need to refit the long data as a *new* design object where `...strata = ~household + v023, ...nest=T`.

Comment: oh right... I didn't see that. Yes what AdamO is saying. The `id` argument is "specifying cluster ids from largest level to smallest level, ~0 or ~1 is a formula for no clusters.". So it'll be `~ hhid` (you don't need to specify the person id if they are the observation unit in this data frame). Then keep strata = `~ v023`

Comment: @AlexJ Since `ids` currently specifies the PSUs (`v021`), I would now need to set `ids= ~v021 + hhid` for the long data, is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure but that sounds about right - is `v021` a spatial cluster or something that preconditions upon selection households? I don't know the survey design - could you briefly explain it to me?

Comment: You don't need to specify both stages of the `id`, since you're already approximating the design as sampling with replacement, you can specify just the coarsest id, `~v021`. It might be clearer to write `~v021+hhid` but it won't affect the results

Comment: @ThomasLumley Thanks for responding. Just to clarify: I can use the same specification for the long data as I'm using the wide, right? i.e., `design_long <- svydesign(ids = ~v021, strata = ~v023, weights = ~I(v005/1e6), nest = T, data=long_data)`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The 'with-replacement' approximation requires the weights, the first-stage PSUs and the first-stage strata.   You might have to fix up the weights, though: the ones you have presumably add to the number of households and you now have a variable number of repeats of each weight.